# Счетчик посещений на ip

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите, как написать такой счетчик вот. Знаю, что начинать надо так:

```
$ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

А дальше не знаю. Знаю только, что записывать дубликаты в базу не должен ип адрессов
и если по базе такой ip не учитывать просмотр.

Answer (score 3):

Выполнять запрос:

```
'INSERT INTO `counter`(`ip`, `long_ip`, `count`) VALUES(' . $ip . ', ' . ip2long($ip) . ', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count` = `count` + 1'
```

`long_ip` - уникальный ключ

Тогда в таблицу будут сохраняться уникальные адреса, если такой уже есть, то увеличится счетчик. В общем так, конечно допиливать под себя нужно

Comment: ок попробуем не получится напишу